# geom_col in R making bars next to each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-analysis, geom-col

With the following code

```
A2c%>%
  group_by (maritalStatus, Geschlecht)%>%
  summarise (nbr_total=n(), nbr_adipos=sum(Adipös))%>%
  mutate( adipos_prozent = 100 * nbr_adipos / nbr_total )%>%
  filter (maritalStatus != "Refused")%>%
  ggplot+
  geom_col(aes(x=maritalStatus, y= adipos_prozent, color = Geschlecht, fill=Geschlecht))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  labs(y = "% Adipöser", x = "Marital Status")
```

I get this plot: [image of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzW6x.png)

Here the woman and man are put on top of each other for each marital status. However I would like to have the bars for men and women next to each other for each marital status. So instead of having for married one bar with male and female I would like to have two bars for married, one for each gender.
I have not found out how to do this. Maybe someone can help?

Maybe the table of the values is helpful: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58guR.png)

Comment: You should add `position = position_dodge(0.8)`in your `geom_col` function : `geom_col(aes(x=maritalStatus, y= adipos_prozent, color = Geschlecht, fill=Geschlecht),position = position_dodge(0.8))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you an idea how the results looks like, I created random numbers with for your data:

```
A2c <- data.frame(maritalStatus = c("Married", "Married", "Widowed", "Widowed", "Divorced", "Divorced", "Separated", "Separated", "Never married", "Never married"),
                  Geschlecht = c("Männlich", "Weiblich", "Männlich", "Weiblich", "Männlich", "Weiblich", "Männlich","Weiblich", "Männlich", "Weiblich"),
                  nbr_total = sample(1:1500, 10),
                  Adipös = sample(1:600, 10))
```

Random data:

```
   maritalStatus Geschlecht nbr_total Adipös
1        Married   Männlich       376    422
2        Married   Weiblich        33    261
3        Widowed   Männlich       989    458
4        Widowed   Weiblich       329    397
5       Divorced   Männlich        41    222
6       Divorced   Weiblich       741    283
7      Separated   Männlich       743    579
8      Separated   Weiblich       236    262
9  Never married   Männlich        85     25
10 Never married   Weiblich       402    145
```

You should set `position_dodge()` in your `geom_col` function to create space between your bars as like @Basti also mentioned. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
A2c%>%
  group_by (maritalStatus, Geschlecht)%>%
  summarise (nbr_total=n(), nbr_adipos=sum(Adipös))%>%
  mutate( adipos_prozent = 100 * nbr_adipos / nbr_total )%>%
  filter (maritalStatus != "Refused")%>%
  ggplot +
  geom_col(aes(x=maritalStatus, y= adipos_prozent, color = Geschlecht, fill=Geschlecht), position = position_dodge(1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  labs(y = "% Adipöser", x = "Marital Status")
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the bars are now nicely displayed. (Don't look at the numbers, they are fake)